# Django: How do you use an image in your template and let your views.py know it was pressed like a button?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to show an image that the user can click on that will act like a button and return the data to my views.py.

For example,

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Selected Other Service to Included Service" class="button" name="Add Other Service"/>
```

will create a very long button which I can "grab" in my views.py with:

```
    add_other_service = request.POST.get('Add Other Service')
```

I can then test add_other_service and term if that was the button pressed. Hence, I can have multiple buttons on the page and determine which one as pressed.

I know I can use the  tag with the type="image" to click on the image, but I cannot find a way to get name of the button in the views.py.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different variations to see if I could get:

```
    <input type="image" src="{% static 'addAndReturn.svg' %}" width="48" height="48"
       name="addAndReturn" class="btTxt submit" title="Add & Return to Edit"/>
```

to work and looking for:

```
        add_and_return = request.POST.get('addAndReturn')
```

in my views.py, I finally printed out the request.POST and found:

```
'addAndReturn.x': ['36'], 'addAndReturn.y': ['30']
```

I do not know html enough to realize I'd get this type of data. When I searched for getting the data from the image, I found out about getting the actual image and not to determine if the image was clicked so I added this to help others look to use the image like a button that returns to the views.py post() and not just use another URL.